# Support both asyncio and synchronous callers

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm the author of [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/), Tor's python library. Recently we migrated to asyncio, but desire to still be usable by synchronous callers.

[We wrote a mixin](https://gitweb.torproject.org/stem.git/tree/stem/util/asyncio.py) that transparently makes any class usable by both asyncio and synchronous callers...

```
import asyncio
import stem.util.asyncio

class Example(stem.util.asyncio.Synchronous):
  async def hello(self):
    return 'hello'

def sync_demo():
  instance = Example()
  print('%s from a synchronous context' % instance.hello())
  instance.stop()

async def async_demo():
  instance = Example()
  print('%s from an asynchronous context' % await instance.hello())
  instance.stop()

sync_demo()
asyncio.run(async_demo())
```

Is there a better way to approach this?

Our wider ecosystem seem to be forking networking libraries into sync/async variants, with [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) and [AIOHTTP](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/index.html) as the most prominent. Are there any libraries out there that demonstrate good support for both kinds of callers without duplicating their API?

Thanks!

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, there is no elegant approach. Tornado had the same problem long ago, you might find their `@gen.coroutine` approach interesting

Comment: The approach you took seems technically correct, but be aware that `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()` comes with a considerable performance penalty, especially coupled with your own logic around it. Before promoting the approach into public API, I would suggest a careful benchmark of the sync and async version of the code to ensure that the overhead introduced by the bridging code is actually acceptable.